# Absolute value in Verilog (sequential design)

Tags: verilog

I want to get a register absolute value inside an `always@` block with a clock but I'm getting the abs of the previous value instead of the current one.
I saw [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18073/finding-absolute-value-in-verilog-data-designated-by-system-c-xilinx-x) before and here is what I am doing:

```
reg signed [7:0] x;
reg signed [7:0] xabs;

...
        always @ (posedge CLK or posedge RST)
              begin
...
               if($signed(x) < 0) 
                xabs <= -$signed(x);
               else
                xabs <= x; 
...
              end
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

waveform:
[waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79PBG.png)

Comment: You do not need '$signed' because you declared 'x' as 'signed'. Anyway, do try to simulate it yourself to see if it works.

Comment: Looks okay, do you have a waveform? Remember that a flopped value after the clock edge is based on the input’s value before the clock edge.

Comment: I've added the waveform. @Greg

Comment: @P.Sally Looks like it is behaving correctly

Comment: It is behaving correctly. The sequential logic assignments are assigned after the rising edge of the next clock. If you expect combinational behavior try this
    `always @ (*) begin
               if($signed(x) < 0) 
                       xabs = -$signed(x);
               else
                      xabs = x; 
    end`

Comment: @siu So can I use this always block inside of my sequential always block?

Comment: @P.Sally: No, you've to replace your always block with mine. It's not possible to get the output in the same cycle in sequential logic.

Comment: @siu What's the solution if I want to use `xabs` in a sequential logic? i.e for choosing the next state in a FSM.

Comment: @P.Sally you cannot use an always block inside another always block, but you can referenced the signals assigned within other always blocks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `always @posedge`, then `xabs` will be assigned a cycle after `x` is assigned.

If you want `xabs` to change as soon as `x` changes, you can use a `always @*` which triggers immediately.

```
reg [32-1:0] xabs;

always @* begin
    ...
    if($signed(x) < 0) 
        xabs = -$signed(x);
    else
        xabs = x; 
    ...
end
```

Our you can make `xabs` a wire and use an `assign`.

```
wire [32-1:0] xabs;

assign xabs = ($signed(x) < 0) ? -$signed(x) : x;
```